# Can I remove the alphabetical section headers from the app list?

Tags: apps

When I first got my phone this weekend, I'm pretty sure there were no alphabetical section headers in the apps list. However, it seems to have suddenly turned on and I'm not quite sure why. I can only guess that it is something that, by default, gets enabled/disabled based on the number of installed apps.

I'd like to just remove them entirely so I have a much cleaner apps list.

Examples...

Before:

> Alarms
>   App Highlights
>   AppSwitch
>   AT&T Code Scanner
>   Calculator
>   Calendar
>   Camera

Now:

> <kbd>a</kbd>
>   Alarms
>   App Highlights
>   AppSwitch
>   AT&T Code Scanner
>   <kbd>c</kbd>
>   Calculator
>   Calendar
>   Camera

To get me a bit clearer on this, I'd like answers to a few questions:

- Is this *actually* something that can be enabled/disabled, or turns itself on/off based on the number of installed apps, or was it always this way and I'm just mis-remembering?
- If the alphabetical headers can be turned off, how do I do it?
- Do these headers provide some additional functionality I'm not seeing - other than to just have some visual landmarks in the apps list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The headers appear when you have more than 40 apps installed, and there is no way to hide them.

You can tap on the letters to jump between them, just like in the People hub. <- one of the nice hidden features in WP!

Comment: I've got 34 items (including the built in bits), yet I've still got the headers, so I don't think uninstalling apps does remove them

Comment: Maybe it's enabled when you go over 40 and never disabled, could also be that different devices have different thresholds.

Comment: I have the same issue I have under 35 apps and I've still got the alphabetical thing

Answer (score 3):

No as my guess jumplist appears not based on apps count. Its Only based on letters count. If you Install new 15th letter app, it appears.

Comment: It depends on how many letters you are having.. If you have 40 apps starts with "A" then it wont appear and its useless there, so as per my guess it based on letters count, and  Windows always logical.

Comment: Nope. I've been trying for a few days and I hate it, just looks messy. I much prefered the list as it was alphabetical order anyway?!!